# Contract deployment error : value.forEach is not a function

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-deployment

This is a simple contract I am trying out with an Ethereum `testrpc` instance.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
/// @title List

// Begin contract defintion
contract List {

    struct ListMembers {
        bytes32 listOwner;
        bytes32[] members;
        uint256 rNumber;
        uint256 aNumber; 
        uint256 uNumber;  
    }

    ListMembers public lm;
    mapping (bytes32 => bool) public addedMembers;

    function List(bytes32 listOwner) {
        lm.listOwner = listOwner;
        lm.rNumber = 10000;
        lm.aNumber = 0;
        lm.uNumber = 0;
    }
}
```

And, this is the `web3.js` code to deploy the contract.

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var fs = require('fs');
//
var ethHttpProvider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545");
var web3 = new Web3(ethHttpProvider);
var abiFile = fs.readFileSync('Lists.abi').toString();
var abiDef = JSON.parse(abiFile);
var byteCode = fs.readFileSync('Lists.bin').toString();
//
var listContract = web3.eth.contract(abiDef);
deployedContract = listContract.new('A',{data: byteCode, from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 4700000});
//
```

And, this is the error I am getting:

```
TypeError: value.forEach is not a function
```

What am I missing?

Comment: i think the error comes from the provided constructor parameter 'A'

Comment: Also data should have a '0x' in front.  Something like `{data: '0x' + byteCode ...}`.

Comment: Yes. What is the correct way of passing argument?

Comment: The correct format is to pass it as an array element as described here. So, it is, `listContract.new(['A'],...)` https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract

Answer (score 1):

The correct format is to pass it as an array element as described in [wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract). So, it is, `listContract.new(['A'],...)`

Comment: web3.js should be validating its input types... so this should be submitted as an issue on their github page.

Comment: I had a similar error with passing the abi the wrong way. It helped to pass the object with a `JSON.parse` after `require()` the file. Like this `JSON.parse(combinedJson.contracts.contractName.abi)`